# How do I set up a picker view to display data from several matrix options?

Tags: arrays, swift, uipickerview

I have 4 text fields in a view controller that will use a single PickerView, but update depending on which text field is active (via the editing did begin action). I can load data from a single test array but cannot find a way to have the picker view switch between several arrays that are preloaded with data queried from Parse.

Also, is there a way to reference the array name from a string? Ex: replacing "testArray" with a variable in the didSelectRow function and setting the variable when the text field becomes active.

Thanks!

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    if activeField == 1 {

        return fieldNameArray[row]

    } else if activeField == 2 {

        return taskCategoryArray[row]

    } else if activeField == 3 {

        return assignedPersonArray[row]

    } else if activeField == 4 {

        return machineUsedArray[row]
    }


    //return testArray[row]

}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    if activeField == 1 {

        return fieldNameArray.count

    } else if activeField == 2 {

        return taskCategoryArray.count

    } else if activeField == 3 {

        return assignedPersonArray.count

    } else if activeField == 4 {

        return machineUsedArray.count
    }


    //return testArray.count

}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if activeField == 1 {

        fieldNameTextField.text = testArray[row]

    } else if activeField == 2 {

        taskCategoryTextField.text = testArray[row]

    } else if activeField == 3 {

        assignedPersonTextField.text = testArray[row]

    } else if activeField == 4 {

        machineryUsedTextField.text = testArray[row]
    }

    pickerView.isHidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the second part of your question.

But for the first part, you are almost there, you just gotta reload the pickerview when one of your textviews becomes active:

```
pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
```

Comment: Hmm that definitely makes sense, assuming I add it to the text field action function, right? For the second part, I'm looking for a way to set a variable in the statement telling the picker view which array to pull data from, so that the source data can change based on the textfield selected. Ex: instead of using the if statements and cases determined by the activeField variable, I could write the single line for titleForRow as "return matrixVariable" and then have a line in each of the "did start editing" functions that sets the matrixVariable as a name for the array to pull the titles from.

Comment: You could just create a variable like "var selectedArray : Array!" and assign it inside the text field action function like "selectedArray = fieldNameArray". Then you can remove all if else checks and simply return what the selectedArray contains "selectedArray[row]" (Of course assuming all the arrays have the same structure. The only thing you gotta be careful with is that you assign this "selectedArray" var with something on your viewDidLoad or it will crash (since its unwrapped)

Comment: if you do not want to make use of so many if else statements just do one thing put a chicken text fields that which field is active and pass that field array to a PickerArray and use this single picker array for all the text Fields Just you need to increase one Array and it will be used for picker and data in PickerArray is fed from active textfield Array and don't forget to reload picker when new text field becomes Active will shorten your code and its loAd by 25+ lines

Comment: Thanks guys! Had to do some digging, turns out the last error message could be solved by declaring any of the arrays used by selectedArray as containing strings (    var selectedArray : Array<String>!), after doing that it seems to be working well. Thanks a ton!